# How to set up this volume integral,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

The three regions in $R^3$ to consider are:

1) $R_1 = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$

2) $R_2 = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 \le a^2\}, 0<a<1$

3) $R_3 = \{(x,y,z): z\ge b(x^2 + y^2) \}, b>0$

I want to compute the volume of the common region.

The problem statement also says,

distinguish two cases:

$ba^2\le \sqrt{1-a^2}$

$ba^2 > \sqrt{1-a^2}$

My thoughts:

So, I think that the common region is the intersection of

1) $x^2 + y^2 \le 1 - z^2$

2) $x^2 + y^2 \le a^2, 0<a<1$

3)$x^2 + y^2 \le \frac{z}{b}, b>0$

So that $x^2 + y^2 \le min \{1-z^2, a^2, \frac{z}{b}\}$

But how can I actually compute the $min$?

After getting the $min$, then I think I can just go to cylindrical coordinates and integrate the 1-function.  But what about the bounds for the height $z$?

Solving (1) for $z$ gives $z\le +/- \sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}$

And (3) gives that $z\ge b(x^2 + y^2)$

So...I'm not really sure about the limits of integration for $z$.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first thing you should observe:  the regions of interest are all rotationally symmetric about the $z$-axis, because with the cylindrical coordinate transformation $$(x,y,z) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, z),$$ we find $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, therefore, all three equations are independent of the angle $\theta$.  Hence it suffices to look at the $rz$-plane inequalities  $$r^2 + z^2 \le 1, \quad r \le a, \quad z \ge br^2$$ in the first quadrant (i.e., $r, z \ge 0$).  The first is bounded by a circle (red curve).  The second region is bounded by a vertical line at a distance $a$ from the origin (green curve).  The third is quite clearly bounded by a parabola through the origin (blue curve).

[image]

Now, the common region of intersection to these three inequalities comprises the region inside the circle, above the parabola, and to the left of the line.  This requires a consideration of different cases, because if the parabola intersects the circle at a distance less than $a$, then the line is irrelevant.  We solve for this condition by noting that if $r^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $z = br^2$, then the intersection occurs at a radius $\rho$ satisfying $$\rho^2 + b^2 \rho^4 = 1.$$  The volume integral is perhaps most easily evaluated by the method of cylindrical shells; i.e., $$V = \int_{r = 0}^R 2\pi r \left(\sqrt{1-r^2} - br^2\right) \, dr,$$ where $R = \min\{\rho,a\}$.

Comment: I would like to know the software you used to plot the above 3D ploting.

Comment: Hi @heropup, thanks so much for your solution - and for the pretty image.  I must admit that my geometric intuition is relatively weak; do you possibly have an explanation ... algebraically, to pin down what the bounds of integration are?  And when you say that we require a consideration of different cases, are you saying that one triple (iterated) integral is not sufficient, and that we will need *several* triple (iterated) integrals to compute this volume?  Thanks so much...

Comment: For someone like me, I of course crave equalities and inequalities on pen and paper, rather than try to visualize the object...to compensate for my lack of geometric intuition...but please feel free to comment further, thanks @heropup,